# VPN in VM -> Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-11.04

i'm running Ubuntu, and use VPN.

i want to know, if my Virtual Machine (Windows 7) uses the same VPN Connection or if i have to use an vpn client in windows also?

best regard